# NodeJS, Passport and Facebook-why can't I log out

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js

Using this example to login and authenticate with Facebook
https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example

My confusion is why I am unable to logout. This is for a single use kiosk based application. I need to force a logout from the app so that each subsequent user gets the default Facebook login dialog. 
I tried doing a HTP DELETE but that only deletes my app from the user's account, it doesn't actually log the user out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...can I award myself the bounty? :)
This call seems to be needed first

```
  res.redirect('https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next='+SERVER_IP+'/logout&access_token='+ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

and then

```
 app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
      req.logout();
      res.redirect('/login/facebook/return');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you log out from your fb account do you mean on facebook.com or on your own website? Logging out on facebook.com doesn't mean you log out everywhere your account is used to login/authenticate.

Comment: Please see my revised question